# Как сделать всплывающее окно с запросом о возрасте?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать окно, которое будет появлятся при переходе по ссылке и спрашивать возраст пользователя?

И, в зависимости от введённой информации либо перенаправлять на другую страничку, либо исчезать, позволяя тем самым просмотреть информацию, содержащуюся на данной странице.

Вот кусок кода неудачной попытки (при вводе числа от 0 до 13 не загружается другая страница, а при вводе от 14 до 200 блок `win_age` не исчезает):

```html
<div class="win_age" id="win_age1">
    <form method="post" class="age_form">
        <label class="label_age">
            Укажите сколько вам лет
            <input type="number" min="0" max="200" class="age" id="age1">
        </label>
        <input onclick="choose_page()" type="submit" value="Готово" class="age_submit">
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //var age=document.getElementById('age').value;
    function choose_page()
    {
        var age = parseInt(document.getElementById('age1').value);
        if(age < 0 || age > 200 ){
            alert('Вы не верно ввели возраст!');
        }
        if (age > 13 && age < 200 ) {
            document.getElementById('win_age1').style.display="none";
        }
        if(age < 14 && age >= 0)
        {
            document.location.replace("courses_2.html");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: пробывали просто использовать функцию prompt?

Comment: Проверил работу кода, вроде работает как задумано, проблема в чем?

Comment: div win_age исчезает на мгновение и снова появляется. И переход по ссылке "document.location.replace("courses_2.html");" не осуществляется.